# Azure Data Factory copy to CosmosDB throttling

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory, throttling

I have an Azure Data Factory pipeline that executes a 'Copy' step which takes a blob file with JSON data and copies it over to my CosmosDB.

The blob file is 75MB and my CosmosDB is scaled to 10.000 RU's (autoscale).
The Azure Data Factory pipeline takes about 5 mins to copy over all the data but the main problem is that the CosmosDB is throttling because of the many requests. When checking out the metrics page the 'Normalized RU Consumption' spikes to 100% instantly.

[image: RU Consumption spike]

I have been looking for a solution where the Data Factory pipeline just spends more time on the copy step instead of trying it this fast. I tried adjusting the settings in the 'Copy' step in Data Factory but that did not change anything at all.
[image: Copy step settings]

Is there another way to make sure that the Data Factory pipeline does not consume all the RU's? It is no problem that the pipeline would run 1 hour+.
Current issue now is that my CosmosDB Database is unavailable at this time because the Data Factory is taking up all the RU's. Other requests are then returned a 429 'Too many requests'.

Any suggestions are welcome!

EDIT:
I have upscaled my CosmosDB to 50.000 RU's just to test out. The data factory pipeline was successful in 2 minutes now. That is good improvement, but it still occupied 100% of the RU's and the database was not available for about 5 minutes (I think CosmosDB still does some tasks after the data factory pipeline got succeeded).
This is what I'd like to prevent, the 100% spikes. It would be ideal that only 50% RU's are utilised and it take double the time. Would this be possible?

Comment: I would think you'd *want* Data Factory to consume all available RU (you're already paying for the RU/sec, why not use it all?). That said: double-check your partitioning strategy, and number of physical partitions. RU/sec gets divided across physical partitions. If you have, say, two physical partitions due to your partition key and storage use, and now you are loading data to primarily one of those two partitions during your copy, that could explain why you run out of RU  capacity faster than expected.

Comment: Well, actually I don't want my datafactory to consume all available RU to be honest. I would like to control it. Whenever my datafactory is running my API to that same CosmosDB collection is failing on all requests because the RU consumption is already on 100%. I'll have a look at my partitioning strategy if I can make improvements but right now it's pretty basic. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: ADF does not have a way to throttle itself on writes. If you really want to restrict how fast data is written to ensure you do not overwhelm your provisioned throughput you could take a look at the Spark Connector. It contains a config which will allow you to configure a throughput budget. More details here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-api-sdk-java-spark-v3

Comment: btw, here's a Spark 3 sample that shows this in action. https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos-spark_3_2-12/Samples/Python/NYC-Taxi-Data/01_Batch.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

**I do not know any way to set a simple RU limit. But...**

Last time I was in this position it did seem to help to **manually limit integration units and parallelism to small numbers**. Smaller number of clients should put SOME upper limit on write throughput. It's not exact science, though. May be it depends on input source type how streamed/parallel the data reading part is to begin with.

Another delaying measure was to **set higher retry interval** for copy action. This way when ADF itself got throttled, it would create openings for other clients to be served. At the cost of increased duration and cost of ADF run. Most likely OK for one-time actions.

I also played with sink **write batch size** to reduce protocol chattiness and improve overall ingestion time. Not so sure how if it affected overall RU usage, so it is most likely an aspect to balance.

**Another trick you could use is to partition input file to smaller chunks** in ADF, push the batches sequentially and introduce small delays between batches yourself to keep some RU available for others between every batch..